# Using Foundation With Yeoman

Tags: yeoman, gruntjs

I'm attempting to build a web project using Yeoman and Foundation.  I have created the basic project and have included the Foundation component using `bower install foundation` however when I run `grunt server` it fails to compile Foundation or move it in to the app tree.  How do I get Yeoman (or grunt) to recognize and compile Foundation?

I'm using Yeoman 1.0.0-beta.3.  Commands run to set up the project are:

```
npm install generator-angular generator-testacular
bower install foundation
yo angular --minsafe
npm install
bower install --dev
grunt server
```

But the compass:server task reports `Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.`

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting used to Yeoman and foundation. But aren't you supposed to add < script > tag in order for grunt to recognize that you intend to use "foundation"?

[From Yeoman getting started](http://yeoman.io/learning/).

```
yo angular 
bower install angular-ui
# then add <script src="components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
# and <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.css"/>
grunt
```